# Why does python dict behave this way?

Tags: python

I have some code written like so:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    STATE_UNKNOWN = 0
    STATE_WILL_PLAY = 1
    STATE_WONT_PLAY = 2
    STATE_READY = 3
    STATE_CHOICES = ((STATE_UNKNOWN, _("Unknown")),
                     (STATE_WILL_PLAY, _("Yes, I'll play")), 
                     (STATE_WONT_PLAY, _("Sorry, can't play")),
                     (STATE_READY, _("I'm ready to play now")))
    ...


    def change_state(self, state):
        assert(state in dict(Invite.STATE_CHOICES))
```

This code works like I want it to, but I'm curious as to why it works this way.  It is admittedly very convenient that it does work this way, but it seems like maybe I'm missing some underlying philosophy as to why that is.

If I try something like:

```
dict((1,2,3), (2,2,3), (3,2,3))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

it doesn't create a dict that looks like

```
{1: (2,3), 2: (2,3), 3: (2,3)}
```

So the general pattern is not to take the first part of the tuple as the key and the rest as the value.  Is there some fundamental underpinning that causes this behavior, or it is just, well, it would be convenient if it did....

Comment: This is really hard to look at. Why didn't you define a dict in the first place instead of constructing one from a tuple of tuples?

Comment: Django choice fields should be a sequence of two-tuples.  Not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's somewhat obvious.  In your example, `(1,2,3)` is a single object.  So the idea behind a dictionary is to map a `key` to a `value` (i.e. object).

So consider the output:

```
>>> dict(((1,(2,3)), (2,(2,3)))).items()
[(1, (2, 3)), (2, (2, 3))]
```

But you can also do something like this:

```
>>> dict((((1,2),3), ((2,2),3)))
[((1, 2), 3), ((2, 2), 3)]
```

Where the `key` is actually an object too!  In this case a tuple also.

So in your example:

```
dict((1,2,3), (2,2,3), (3,2,3))
```

how do you know which part of each tuple is the key and which is the value?

If you find this annoying, it's a simple fix to write your own constructor:

```
def special_dict(*args):
    return dict((arg[0], arg[1:]) for arg in args)
```

Also, to Rafe's comment, you should define the dictionary right away:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    STATE_UNKNOWN = 0
    STATE_WILL_PLAY = 1
    STATE_WONT_PLAY = 2
    STATE_READY = 3
    STATE_CHOICES = dict(((STATE_UNKNOWN, _("Unknown")),
                     (STATE_WILL_PLAY, _("Yes, I'll play")), 
                     (STATE_WONT_PLAY, _("Sorry, can't play")),
                     (STATE_READY, _("I'm ready to play now"))))
    ...


    def change_state(self, state):
        assert(state in Invite.STATE_CHOICES)
```

If you ever want to iterate over the states, all you have to do is:

```
for state, description = Invite.STATE_CHOICES.iteritems():
    print "{0} == {1}".format(state, description)
```

The construction of the dictionary in your `change_state` function is unnecessarily costly.

When you define the Django field, just do:

```
models.IntegerField(sorted(choices=Invite.STATE_CHOICES.iteritems()))
```

Comment: Once I knew how it worked, it seemed obvious to me as well.  I'm just thinking what made it obvious to the implementers of the language that it should be that way.  Sometimes learning the why of things leads to greater understanding of other things.

Comment: Guido is a smart guy I guess? :)

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `dict` accepts (among other things) a sequence of `(key, value)` tuples.  Your second examples passes a list of tuples of length 3 instead of 2, and hence fails.

```
dict([(1, (2, 3)), (2, (2, 3)), (3, (2, 3))])
```

however will create the dictionary

```
{1: (2, 3), 2: (2, 3), 3: (2, 3)}
```

Comment: He's not asking how to do what he wants, he's asking why the `dict` constructor is designed the way it is.

Comment: @milky, the answer to that is given in the question. It works that way because it's a very convenient way to construct dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern is just this: you can create a dict from a list (in general: iterable) of *pairs*, treated as (key, value). Anything longer would be arbitrary: why (1,2,3)->{1:(2,3)}  and not (1,2,3)-> {(1,2):3}?

Moreover, the pairs<->dict conversion is obviously two-way. With triples it couldn't be (see the above example).